# Does Vulkan invoke work groups of a compute shader in the correct order?

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

When I invoke `vkCmdDispatch` the GPU will try to run as many groups in parallel as possible. If there are too many groups, then some of them will have to wait for others to complete before there is space (like some available warps on nvidia) for them.
I want to know if Vulkan somehow guarantees that groups with lower `gl_WorkGroupID` will run before those with higher `gl_WorkGroupID`. So for example if I write code like

```
if(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x==0){
   // some preliminary setup
}
```

then I can be sure that this code will be executed at the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work group execution is entirely unordered, and there's basically no effective tool to *force* execution of work groups in any particular order.